# method contains returns null in streamBuilder flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, contains, stream-builder

I am trying to remove posts from the list of user posts that were hidden. been struggling with it fo r a few days now. So, came down to the following code:

```
 return StreamBuilder(
  stream: postRef.snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final documents = snapshot.data.docs
          .removeWhere((snapshot) =>
       snapshot.data() 
 ['hidingUserId'].contains(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid) ? true : 
 false).toList();
      if (documents.length == 0) {blahblahblah}
```

this, however gives me null error:

```
The method 'contains' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: contains("currentuiser Id in the firebase firestore")
```

hidingUserId is the array of userIds that have hidden the posts, and some arrays do have the currentuserId in them. Thanks for your help!

firestore data: [image: firestoredata]

Comment: can you assure that your field is correctly spelled and the data is there?

Comment: I added the firestore data screenshot. the Yh4 blabhalh is the current userId, my userId

Comment: You are taking the reference at wrong node or maybe ,I can see the auth id of collection key and the key inside hidingUserId is different.

Comment: First step is to make a print statement in your console to see what kind of data you retrieved. Please do that and post the result. Another question: what is the reason you use a streambuilder?

Comment: Later i use streamBuilderWrapper to order the results according to some criteria, for instance timestamp, stars or likes...

Comment: are you sure, that your postRef.snapshots() function is returning the correct stream to the correct document? In other words, can you access the data coming from that document in your code, e.g. with a print statement?

Comment: I noticed you have a blank document above your current document (by blank I mean the name of the document is " "), if said document does not contain a value in hidingUserId or does not contain hidingUserId then the value returned from `.data()['hidingUserId']` and/or `.data().hidingUserId` will always be `null`, so you will be calling `null` when your query iterates over the results.

Comment: I see, so does that mean I need to add a null check before calling .contains method?

Comment: Yes. If the null check returns true, return false to the filter.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention: should this solve your issue, please let me know, that way I can compile it into a community wiki answer. Thanks